# Using Three20's TTThumbsViewController in conjunction with TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, three20

I've been struggling to get TTThumbsViewController to work with my application's tab bar and navigation.  Bit-by-bt, I've solved most of the problems.  The first problem is what I see when I get to what is supposed to be a full-screen image view.  It is creating a white block where the status bar used to be.  See screen-shots...

[alt text http://irovr.com/img/temp/a01.png](http://irovr.com/img/temp/a01.png)
[alt text http://irovr.com/img/temp/a02.png](http://irovr.com/img/temp/a02.png)
[alt text http://irovr.com/img/temp/a03.png](http://irovr.com/img/temp/a03.png)
[alt text http://irovr.com/img/temp/a04.png](http://irovr.com/img/temp/a04.png)
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding the view controller to a navigation controller and modally displaying that.

Answer (score 1):

My PhotoBrowserViewController is a subclass of TTThumbsViewController

```
PhotoBrowserViewController *photoView = [[PhotoBrowserViewController alloc] init];
photoView.delegate = self;
photoView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

UINavigationController *photoNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[photoNav pushViewController:photoView animated:NO];
[photoView release];

[self presentModalViewController:photoNav animated:YES];

[photoNav release];
```

I did this code when I was beginning iPhone development and it's probably crap.  Since then I've avoided tab controllers because of all the problems I encountered with them.